# Fixing generic Swift Crashlytics bug

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm struggling to figure out the source of a bug that has affected a decent amount of my users. I am using swift 2.0 and have crashlytics paired up, but the crash report is leaving me clueless! :

EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe

NewGroupShareInstructionsViewController.swift line 48
NewGroupShareInstructionsViewController.(dismissImageView(UIGestureRecognizer) -> ()).(closure #1)

Here is the relevant code (let me know if you want more)

```
@IBAction func butPreviewPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Step\(sender.tag)"))
        imageView.frame = self.view.frame
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.frame = CGRectZero
        imageView.center = sender.center
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissImageView:")
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        self.lastButtonPressed = sender
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
            self.navigationController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            imageView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        }
    }

func dismissImageView(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let imageView = recognizer.view!
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            imageView.frame = CGRectZero
            imageView.center = self.lastButtonPressed!.center
        }) { (completed) in
            if completed {
                self.lastButtonPressed = nil
                imageView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.navigationController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }
        }

    }
```

Hoping someone can help me figure this out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of force unwrapping going on (`!`). I'd suggest that you switch to using `if let` statements instead - any single one of those unwraps could be causing your crash. My best guess is that it's the `self.lastButtonPressed!` call, given that the log says it's in the first closure, which that is.